# Find the parent node by giving a child node using PowerShell from JSON

Tags: json, powershell

I have a JSON file as given below.

```json
{
    "pr": {
        "nv": "1234.0.0.234",
        "ps": [{
                "nv": "1234.1.1.235",
                "fh": [{
                        "nv": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "nv": ""
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "nv": "1234.102.000.579",
                "fh": [{
                        "nv": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "nv": ""
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "nv": "1234.103.000.111",
                "fh": [{
                        "nv": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "nv": ""
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "nv": "1234.104.000.134",
                "fh": [{
                        "nv": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "nv": ""
                    }
                ],
                "SP": [{
                        "nv": "1234.105.000.245",
                        "fh": [{
                                "nv": ""
                            },
                            {
                                "nv": ""
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "nv": "1234.106.000.306",
                        "fh": [{
                                "nv": ""
                            },
                            {

                                "nv": ""
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "pr": {
            "nv": "2234.000.000.115",
            "ps": [{
                    "nv": "1234.1.1.235",
                    "fh": [{
                            "nv": ""
                        },
                        {
                            "nv": ""
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "nv": "2234.102.000.579",
                    "fh": [{
                            "nv": ""
                        },
                        {
                            "nv": ""
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "nv": "2234.103.000.111",
                    "fh": [{
                            "nv": ""
                        },
                        {
                            "nv": ""
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "nv": "2234.104.000.134",
                    "fh": [{
                            "nv": ""
                        },
                        {
                            "nv": ""
                        }
                    ],
                    "SP": [{
                            "nv": "2234.105.000.245",
                            "fh": [{
                                    "nv": ""
                                },
                                {
                                    "nv": ""
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "nv": "2234.106.000.306",
                            "fh": [{
                                    "nv": ""
                                },
                                {
                                    "nv": ""
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I want to read the dependency versios of the given version. For exmple if i provide the version 2234.106.000.306 then it should return an array of values
[1234.0.0.234,2234.000.000.115,2234.104.000.134,2234.106.000.306].

I am able to do it using foreach loop. But i would like to know is thier any other better way to achieve it

```bsh
$tv = "1234.106.000.306"
$dv = @()

function Processependency($splist) {
    foreach ($ps in $splist) {
        if ($ps.nv -eq $tv) {
            $dv += $ps.nv
            return $dv
        }
        foreach ($fh in $ps.fh) {
            if ($fh.nv -eq $tv) {
                $dv += $fh.nv
                return $dv
            }
        }
        foreach ($SP in $ps.SP) {
            if ($SP.nv -eq $tv) {
                $dv += $ps.nv
                $dv += $SP.nv
                return $dv
            }
        }
    }
}

$JsonFile = Get-Content -Raw -Path $Filepath | ConvertFrom-Json

foreach ($pr in $JsonFile.pr) {
    $dv += $pr.nv
    if ($pr.nv -eq $tv) {
        return ($dv)
    } else {
        $dv = Processependency($pr.ps)
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if that's obvious, but from your description I don't know how you find the dependencies based on given version number.

Comment: You'll want a recursive function for this.

Answer (score 1):

Recursion is easier than iteration when it comes to tasks like this.

```bsh
function List-Dependencies($data, $version) {
    if ($data.nv -eq $version) {
        # if version attribute has the specified version: return the value
        return $data.nv
    } else {
        # otherwise recurse into the other properties
        $result = @($data.PSObject.Properties.Name | Where-Object {
            $_ -ne 'nv'
        } | ForEach-Object {
            $data.$_ | ForEach-Object { List-Dependencies $_ $version }
        })
        # and return the result (append the version number of the current node if
        # it has one)
        if ($result) {
            if ($data.nv) { $result += $data.nv }
            return $result
        }
    }
}
```

This will recurse into your data until it either finds the given version string or no child nodes are left. If the version string is found it is returned, and as the calls traverse back upwards version numbers from the parent nodes are added.

The result will have the version numbers in the opposite order of what you specified (topmost node last), so if you need them in inverse order you need to either reverse the result or prepend the version of the parent node to `$result` instead of appending.